# Set OnePlus 3t alert slider to all/vibrate/silent

Tags: android, alert, notificationmanager, oneplusthree

I have a OnePlus 3t running on OOS Open Beta 15, Android 7.1.1. I want its alert slider to put my phone into all sounds/vibration only/silent mode respectively. After trying every possible combination of third party apps and Tasker profiles, I started looking into creating my own Magisk Module to change the slider's behavior.

I found out that all the alert slider logic is inside the package `com.oneplus.threekey`. Using

```
adb shell 'pm list packages' > C:\packages.txt
```

I go a list of all my installed packages and the only packages containing the word "oneplus" are the following ones:

```
package:com.oneplus
package:com.oneplus.aod
package:com.oneplus.applocker
package:com.oneplus.calculator
package:com.oneplus.camera
package:com.oneplus.camera.service
package:com.oneplus.config
package:com.oneplus.deskclock
package:com.oneplus.dirac.simplemanager
package:com.oneplus.gallery
package:com.oneplus.iconpack.dives
package:com.oneplus.iconpack.o2default
package:com.oneplus.iconpack.rifon
package:com.oneplus.ifaaservice
package:com.oneplus.opbackup
package:com.oneplus.opbugreport
package:com.oneplus.opbugreportlite
package:com.oneplus.oplocationservice
package:com.oneplus.screenshot
package:com.oneplus.sdcardservice
package:com.oneplus.security
package:com.oneplus.setupwizard
package:com.oneplus.simcontacts
package:com.oneplus.skin
package:com.oneplus.sms.smscplugger
package:com.oneplus.soundrecorder
package:com.oneplus.wallpaper
package:com.oneplus.wifiapsettings
```

After no getting anywhere this way, I decided to look further into my logcat output. Filtering it using "threekey" this is the output everytime I change the alert slider's position:

```
10-03 00:00:53.223 1407-1872/? D/ThreeKeyHw: OEM UEVENT: {SUBSYSTEM=switch, SEQNUM=11574, ACTION=change, SWITCH_STATE=3, SWITCH_NAME=tri-state-key, DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/switch/tri-state-key}
10-03 00:00:53.227 1407-1407/? D/ThreeKeyAudioPolicy: set mode ring, mVibrateFlag=false, mMuteMediaFlag=true
10-03 00:00:53.231 1407-1407/? D/ZenModeHelper: setConfigLocked reason=ThreeKeyAudioPolicy
                                                java.lang.Throwable
                                                    at com.android.server.notification.ZenModeHelper.setConfigLocked(ZenModeHelper.java:706)
                                                    at com.android.server.notification.ZenModeHelper.setManualZenMode(ZenModeHelper.java:543)
                                                    at com.android.server.notification.ZenModeHelper.setManualZenMode(ZenModeHelper.java:503)
                                                    at com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$5.setZenMode(NotificationManagerService.java:2193)
                                                    at android.app.NotificationManager.setZenMode(NotificationManager.java:422)
                                                    at com.oneplus.threekey.ThreeKeyAudioPolicy.setRing(ThreeKeyAudioPolicy.java:177)
                                                    at com.oneplus.threekey.ThreeKeyAudioPolicy.setDown(ThreeKeyAudioPolicy.java:87)
                                                    at com.oneplus.threekey.ThreeKey.setDown(ThreeKey.java:46)
                                                    at com.oneplus.threekey.ThreeKeyBase.setSwitchState(ThreeKeyBase.java:54)
                                                    at com.oneplus.threekey.ThreeKeyBase$ThreeKeyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ThreeKeyBase.java:80)
                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1163)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:367)
                                                    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:237)
                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
10-03 00:00:53.298 2002-2087/? I/vol.VolumeDialogControl: s updateZenModeW zen:0 threeKeySatus:3 mVibrateWhenMute:0
10-03 00:00:53.300 1407-1407/? D/ThreeKeyAudioPolicy: settings change selfChange=false uri=content://settings/global/zen_mode
10-03 00:00:53.301 1407-1407/? D/ThreeKeyAudioPolicy: zen mode was changed, zen mode=ZEN_MODE_OFF, three key status=3
10-03 00:00:53.302 2002-2087/? I/vol.VolumeDialogControl: s updateZenModeW zen:0 threeKeySatus:3 mVibrateWhenMute:0
10-03 00:00:53.306 2002-2002/? D/VolumeUI: mZenModeObserver:zenMode=3, threeKeyStatus=3, mLastThreeKeyStatus=2
10-03 00:00:53.314 2002-2002/? D/VolumeUI: mZenModeObserver:zenMode=3, threeKeyStatus=3, mLastThreeKeyStatus=3
```

Here I noticed in the Throwable part that the threekey class/service (I don't really know what that is tbh) calls `setZenMode`, which seems to be responsible for the notification sounds. But as it turns out the `setZenMode` method is not documented at [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) and can't be called after obtaining an instance of the NotificationManager class.

At this point I am beginning to run out of ideas what to try next or where else to look. Any help to get the slider to work like it used to would be great!